# Give alert when the file is download from the attachment in android

Tags: android

I download the *.ics file successfully from the mail attachment by using
intent-filter.
    I need to give an alert at the time of downloading the ics file. How to do this? Please help me to solve.This I am new to android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can use the help of thread for this.